# Ansible check if value exists in dictionary list

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Below is my variable list

```
hostlist:
  - { name: 'host1', ip_addr: '192.168.2.31', hostgrp: 'physical_workstation' }
  - { name: 'host2', ip_addr: '192.168.2.32', hostgrp: 'physical_workstation' }
  - { name: 'host3', ip_addr: '192.168.2.33', hostgrp: 'virtual_machine' }
```

I treid below

```
- name: Conditional test
  debug:
    msg: "hello world"
  when: hostlist|selectattr("name", "equalto", "host1")|list|length != 0
```

This does not work as showing below error

```
The error was: TemplateRuntimeError: no test named 'equalto'
```

There is solution of upgrding Jinaj2. But is there any other method instead of using selectattr. I wish not to upgrade Jinja2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the list of names and test the name is [*in*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-tests.in) the list, e.g.

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "hello world"
      loop:
        - 'host1'
        - 'host9'
      when: item in _names
      vars:
        _names: "{{ hostlist|map(attribute='name')|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => (item=host1) => 
  msg: hello world
skipping: [localhost] => (item=host9)
```

---

**Check only host1**

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "hello world"
      when: "'host1' in _names"
      vars:
        _names: "{{ hostlist|map(attribute='name')|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => (item=host1) => 
  msg: hello world
```